# Is Batesian mimicry more important for females?

Tags: entomology, adaptation, arachnology, sexual-dimorphism, antipredator-adaptation

*Myrmarachne plataleoides*  is a jumping spider that mimics the Kerengga or weaver ant (*Oecophylla smaragdina*) in both morphology and behaviour. However, the two sexes appear different:

[image]
*Myrmarachne plataleoides* (Female)

[image]
*Myrmarachne plataleoides* (Male)

Some links suggest that in dimorphic arthropods the females more exactly mimic the model. Is this true? If so, why would this sex difference exist?

**Reference**
[Phyologenetics of mimicry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetics_of_mimicry)

Comment: I slightly edited your question. However, the reference link is empty. I like this question a lot. +1

Comment: @AliceD:Sorry I just put insects there, LOL.....thank you for ur answer and edition. You did well

Comment: All good! Thanks for the interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sexually dimorphic ant-mimicking spiders, it depends on the specific species which sex resembles the ant most [(Cushing, 2012)](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/psyche/2012/151989/).

In many cases of sexually dimorphic spider myrmecomorphs, the male is more mimetic than the female, such as in *Corinnidae* species and the genus *Castianeira*, *Oonopidae* and *Antoonops*.

Such sexual dimorphism may be adaptive if the sexes are exposed to different predation pressures. The spider's mimicry of noxious ant species yields protective benefit from predators who would avoid the ants. However, the mimicry often results in being more conspicuous in their color markings than related spider species that are more camouflaged. Hence, conspicuousness can be considered a cost of Batesian mimicry. A palatable species may be evolutionary maximizing its level of protection for the smallest cost (in terms of conspicuousness). Sexual dimorphism, in which the more **active sex** (which, in spiders, is **typically the males**) evolves mimetic resemblance to noxious ants, whereas the other sex remains relatively more concealed and camouflaged behaviorally and morphologically.

**Reference**
[Cushing, *psyche* (2012); **151989**: 1-24](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/psyche/2012/151989/)

Comment: Great reference - wonderful review of a very interesting association!

Comment: "whereas the other sex remains relatively more concealed and camouflaged behaviorally and morphologically." this points towards the female, but the female is the more closest resemblance. Then how could it be called as concealed and camouflaged. Do you mean the resemblance itself is camouflage ?

Comment: @Jay, The author says that it is often the males that mimic the ants more closely, see the bolded-out text

Comment: The male (Myrmarachne plataleoides) pictured have a pair of fangs, which make it differ from the female counter part. So here the female is the closest mimic and without these fangs the males would be too. I think these fangs are for display.

Comment: agreed, totally. it depends on the species.

Comment: the article you referred seems awesome.

Comment: One more think. male spiders(most males) needs some extra decorations and attachments in order to attract females and catch a fight for sex. The males are considered to be more mimetic but they do have an overhead of putting up these male display, in this case they may vary from the model. Isnt ?

Comment: @Jay  - I am not an enthomologist, but from what I understand your theory is correct and mimicry and sexual dimporphism is species dependent. I however don't know if spider males fight, for one thing.